# Ruby - why can't and / or statements be on a separate line?

Tags: ruby, scripting

I am writing a very simple ruby script and has a few checks:

```
if true and true and true then

else

end
```

Why can I not format it this way

```
if true
   and true
   and true
   then

else

end
```

Ruby blows up if I do it that way.  I want do do it that way so my lines are crazy long.  I simply made the criteria a function so that solves the problem, but I still feel very limited if I can't put that onto a separate line.

Walter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also write it:

```
if true and
  true and
  true
    puts "true"
end
```

Comment: Ah okay, I thought I had tried that, I definitely ain't doing the \.  My code has to look somewhat pretty for me to brand my name on it.  That'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `\` to continue the line:

```
if true \
   and true \
   and true
   puts "true!"
end
```

It's not the best style, but it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses will do the trick as well:

```
if(true
   and true
   and true)
  puts "true!"
end
```

Making the criteria a function, as you already did, is probably a superior solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can -- just drop the 'then'.

/I think :)